# How to highlight points from and hist chart in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have some troubles with my code. I'm very very beginner in R, so I would like some help. I have a dataframe and I need to make an hist chart and then highlight some points. But I cannot understand how to find those points in my dataset. Here is and example of what I have.

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d","f","g","h","i","j","k")
y <- c(197421,77506,130474,18365,30470,22518,70183,15378,29747,11148)
z <- data.frame(x,y)
hist(z$y)
```

For example, how can I find in the hist where is the "a" and "h" value placed? and in a barplot? I tried the function *points*, but I cannot find the coordinates. Please let me know how could I make that . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. The approach is to `cut` the `y` variable into bins and then use `summarise` to create the counts and the labels.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
z %>% 
  mutate(bins = cut(y, seq(0, 200000, 50000))) %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  summarise(xes = paste0(x, collapse = ", "),
            count = n()) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = bins, y = count), stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "grey") +
  geom_text(aes(x = bins, y = count + 0.5, label = xes)) +
  xlab("y")
```

[image]

Here is a more complicated way that makes a plot that looks more like what `hist()` produces.

```
z2 <- z %>% 
  mutate(bins = cut(y, seq(0, 200000, 50000))) %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  summarise(xes = paste0(x, collapse = ", "),
            count = n()) %>%
  separate(bins, into = c("start", "end"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(across(start:end, ~as.numeric(str_remove(., "\\(|\\]")))) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = z, aes(x = y), breaks = seq(0, 200000, 50000),
                 color = "black", fill = "grey") +
  geom_text(data = z2, aes(x = (start + end) / 2, y = count + 0.5, label = xes))
```

[image]

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for anwer me, but I cannot me able to use any library for this task. I think I dont explained me well. I should make a plot and select what point is for example, the value of "a". Is there a way to select one point and verify with value is ? or maybe to find the right coordinates of the plot. Thank you very much as well.